# Fundamental impediments for non-static access from inner classes to outer interfaces

Tags: java, static, java-8

Example:

```
interface Outer {
    default String get() {
        return "hi";
    }
    class Inner {
        String got() {
            return get();
        }
    }
}
```

This yields the error

> java: non-static method get() cannot be referenced from a static context.

The inner interface/class is always static; unlike with an outer class where it's non-static unless declared static.

This is how things are today and in the upcoming java 8. Is there a fundamental reason for this difference between outer classes and outer interfaces?

**Update**:
After reading @Radiodef´s comment I changed the inner interface to be an inner class. An outer class can't contain a non-static inner interface so the example was confusing. An inner class is really what I would like anyway.

**Update**: For reference. This is perfectly legal:

```
class Outer {
    String get() {
        return "hei";
    }
    class Inner {
        String got() {
            return get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before Java 8, I'd say that it's because interfaces aren't objects and don't contain data (you can't have a non-static member field); adding data to interfaces makes implementation more complicated, because multiple inheritance is allowed on interfaces; and a non-static inner interface would have to have a pointer to the outer object, which is data.  I don't know if that's still true in Java 8.

Comment: Just to clarify, more generally you are wondering why an interface cannot have an inner class? (Because an interface cannot have an inner class either.) You also cannot have an 'inner interface' for a normal class.

Comment: In Java, there's nothing forcing you to have an `Inner` implementation inside an `Outer` implementation and thus `Inner` can't know anything about `Outer`.

Comment: @Darkhogg an inner class/interface knows about the outer _class_

Comment: Non-static Inner **class instances** know about the enclosing outer **class instance**, because they carry an implicit reference to it. I doubt that interfaces can do that, as they are not permitted to contain state. That also explains, why your code cannot work as intended - there is no reference to an instance of `Outer` on which `get()` could be invoked.

Comment: Upvoted because I actually do not see a technical reason this should not be possible. Inner classes are *considered* as "members of an instance" but behind the scenes they do not work that way.

Comment: @Pyranja I changed the example to be an inner _class_ (my fault; see update); the inner class should be able to carry a reference to the outer interface

Comment: Though the true answer to this question may be one only the Java designers can give. ; )

Comment: Except for the language specification, which defines that member types declared in an interface are implicitly public and static, indeed there seems to be no technical reason. On the other hand, I do not see a reason to require such an exotic construct. Afaik the main (only) purpose of non-static inner class is to preserve encapsulation, but allow collaboration between two objects. But in the case of interfaces, there is no encapsulation to preserve - as by definition all members of an interface are publicly accessible.

Comment: `String string = new Outer() {}.new Inner().got();` - would be valid code.

Comment: All class and interface members of an interface are implicitly `static`. 'Non-static inner' is a tautology. There is no inner class here. Only a static class. It is misnamed, and your question therefore ill-formed.

Comment: The whole idea behind the question is why is it so. At the point where default methods got access to the interface object; so could presumably inner classes

Answer (score 9):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but your code snippet is exactly equivalent to

```
interface Outer {
    public default String get() {
        return "hi";
    }
    public static class Inner {
        String got() {
            return get();
        }
    }
}
```

As [the JLS Chapter 9.5 (Java 8)](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/se/8/java-se-8-pfd-spec/java-se-8-jls-pfd-diffs.pdf) states

> A member type declaration in an interface is implicitly `public` and
>   `static`. It is permitted to redundantly specify either or both of these
>   modifiers.

So if you did

```
Inner innerInstance = new Outer.Inner();
innerInstance.got();
```

what would `get()` be invoked on? There is no object of type `Outer` involved here.

> Is there a fundamental reason for this difference between outer
>   classes and outer interfaces?

This isn't the issue. **Your class code is an example of [inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)**, ie. non `static` nested class. **The interface code is an example of a `static` nested class**. You are comparing two different things.

The equivalent example with a `static` nested class within an enclosing class would be

```
class Outer {
    String get() {
        return "hei";
    }

    public static class Inner {
        String got() {
            return get(); // won't compile
        }
    }
}
```

where again it doesn't make sense for `get()` to work since there is no corresponding (enclosing) instance to invoke it on.

---

If the question, as [@Radiodef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418802/fundamental-impediments-for-non-static-access-from-inner-classes-to-outer-interf/21420600?noredirect=1#comment32316497_21420600) put it, is

> why must the class be implicitly static beyond that this is the
>   existing spec?

then my answer is the following:

An interface, by definition, is

> A point at which independent systems or diverse groups interact

An interface does not have state and it does not have behavior. It simply describes behavior. Interface members are implicitly `static` because an interface does not have state.

Comment: I think the question is not *"why doesn't this work?"* but *"why shouldn't this work?"* Or to put it another way, *"why must the class be implicitly static beyond that this is the existing spec?"*

Comment: @Radiodef My edit is the best I could do to answer that.

Comment: It's the inner class that will need to hold a reference to the outer interface and not reverse. Prior to Java 8 I can acknowledge the argument about behavior in interface, but with extension methods the argument is redundant.

Comment: @thoredge Are you proposing that Java 8+ interfaces should now support declaring both `static` and non-`static` nested classes?

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a way for you to remember it.

1. For a `static` member, it's not bound to an object of the declaring class/interface; for a non-`static` member, it has to bound to an object of the declaring class.
2. All interface's members are implicitly `static`, except `default` ones.

So, in your Exemple: `static class Inner` is not bound to an object of `interface Outer`(Since there is no meaning of *object of `interface`*), so it can't call the member of `Outer`.

For your legal one in the **Update**: `class Inner` is bound to an object of `class Outer`, so when you create an object of `Inner`, you also create an anonymous object of `class Outer`, so when you call `get()` in `Inner::got()`, the `get()` is called upon that anonymous object.

Hope this help.

Comment: It didn't help. Default methods use the object of interface; so presumably so could in theory inner classes. Not currently of course, but in principle

Comment: @thoredge: Could you provide the source of "Default methods use the object of interface"? My current idea is default methods are bound to inheriting subclasses objects...

Comment: Yes; and in the same way the internal member class can be bound to inheriting subclass objects. I interpreted your 'object of interface' to mean that